# Validação de data com Zend

Tags: zend

Como fazer a validação de uma data usando Zend?
Quando o usuário se cadastra, preciso validar a data de aniversario e ver se é maior que 18 anos.

Recebo 3 campos - dia, mês e ano e gostaria de validar o cadastro apenas para maiores de 18

Encontrei este código, mas não sei como devo informar o parâmetro +18

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_Date(array(
    'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    'locale' => $yourLocale
);
```

obrigado

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois está ampla demais a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara, quando a pessoa informar a data de aniversário você pode pegar verificar se a data que ele informou é anterior a data para se ter 18 anos.

Por exemplo: Se o cara disse que nasceu em 1998-07-07, essa data posterior a mínima para ter 18 anos (Que seria no ano de 1996). Para fazer essas verificações se é antes ou depois da data pode usar os métodos abaixo:

```
$dateOne = new Zend_Date(time());
$dateTwo = new Zend_Date(time());

 // verifica se a segunda data é posteRior a segunda 
if ($dateOne->isLater($dateTwo)) {
 // BLABLA
}
  // verifica se a primeira data é antes da segunda
if ($dateOne->isEarlier($dateTwo)) {
 // BLABLA
}
```

Comment: isLater e isEarlier estao disponiveis no zend 2.2?

Comment: Sim estão, aqui o local para baixar a versão estável dele: http://framework.zend.com/blog/zend-framework-2-2-0-stable-released.html
Marca a resposta como útil, clicando na setinha pra cima se puder! Obrigado! ^^

Comment: na versao que eu tenho nao encontrei, isLater e isEarlier... vou baixar o que recomendou e procura-los. ja dei como resolvido, obrigado